# In WASM Blazor using Azure Active Directory, how do I bypass Auth during development

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor

Authenticating WASM Blazor against Azure Active Directory is covered nicely by Microsoft in their walkthroughs. What they don't cover is the development workflow afterwards. Being a compiled application, every change to the UI is a painful stop-recompile-start process, which is then compounded by an AAD login process.
How do we streamline this and set a fake set of credentials during development?

Answer (score 6):

This approach works for me, for now, but I am keen to see what others do. Note this is primarily for development, but I could look to extend this for integration tests (which is next on my list).

In the client, make yourself a fake AuthenticationStateProvider to replace the Remote authentication one you normally use.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;

namespace Blah.Client
{
    public class FakeAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider, IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ">> TEST USER <<"),
                new Claim("directoryGroup","abc4567-890-1234-abcd-1234567890abc") //Should match your group you use to determine a policy
            }, "Fake authentication type");


            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);



            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }

        public async ValueTask<AccessTokenResult> RequestAccessToken()
        {
            return new AccessTokenResult(AccessTokenResultStatus.Success, new AccessToken() { Expires = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(365,0,0,0) }, "");
        }

        public async ValueTask<AccessTokenResult> RequestAccessToken(AccessTokenRequestOptions options)
        {
            return new AccessTokenResult(AccessTokenResultStatus.Success, new AccessToken() { Expires = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0) }, "");
        }
    }
}
```

In the client program.cs, switch out the auth when in debug:

```
#if DEBUG
            SetupFakeAuth(builder.Services);
#else
            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://1234567-890-1234-abcd-1234567890abc/API.Access");
            })
                .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();
#endif
.....
        private static void SetupFakeAuth(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                //https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L28

            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            services.TryAddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, FakeAuthStateProvider>();


            services.TryAddTransient<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
            services.TryAddTransient<AuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            services.TryAddScoped(sp =>
            {
                return (IAccessTokenProvider)sp.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
            });

            services.TryAddScoped<IAccessTokenProviderAccessor, FakeAccessTokenProviderAccessor>();
            services.TryAddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>();           
        }
```

...
And define the FakeAuthState provider, which is just a copy of the internal class Microsoft register:

```
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.Internal
{
    internal class FakeAccessTokenProviderAccessor : IAccessTokenProviderAccessor
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
        private IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

        public FakeAccessTokenProviderAccessor(IServiceProvider provider) => _provider = provider;

        public IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider => _tokenProvider ??= _provider.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>();
    }
}
```

This should result in a logged in user on the client that has a name and Scopes as usual.

Server side:

in Startup.cs

```
    #if DEBUG            
        services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, FakePolicyEvaluator>();
    #else                        
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    
    #endif
```

and a new class:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Blah.Server
{
    public class FakePolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
    {
        public virtual async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
        {
            const string testScheme = "FakeScheme";
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim("Permission", "CanViewPage"),
                new Claim("Manager", "yes"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "John")
            }, testScheme));
            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties(), testScheme)));
        }

        public virtual async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy,
            AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone. I'll now look to improve this and make it work in testing scenarios.

Comment: This is great. On the server AuthenticateAsync I think you need to assign the ClaimsPrincipal to context.User otherwise the user apears to be blank on the server side. I also moved the ClaimsPrincipal creation to shared code rather than similar on Client and Server.